# How to get postInstallScriptUri information of SoftLayer vitual guest?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I created a SoftLyaer VM with postInstallScriptUri option. It looks like that I can retrieve postInstallScriptUri using SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getObject with objectMask postInstallScriptUri or supplementalCreateObjectOptions[postInstallScriptUri]. But,both of them returns empty value in my test. Is there any way to get postInstallScriptUri value of VMs using SoftLayer API?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the **postInstallScriptUri** key is outdated, it's not possible to retrieve post install scripts from vms through API. The only way would be to check inside of the vms's history.